# Wood glue sufficient to repair separated shelf?

Tags: adhesive, shelving

My home has a 17” x 36” x 1” shelf that appears to have only been secured by glue to the surface above it. It’s separated slightly but hasn’t moved much in 2 years: [image]

The shelf has extra bracing wood adding weight:[image]

Would wood glue be sufficient to reattach this at all, or should I use some form of screw? I was hoping to only attach vertically if so. However, there is a stud in the wall at the far edge, not just drywall. That seems to be the best long term approach.

Comment: The best glue joints start with very clean mated surfaces.  No dirt, paint, or old glue.  Screws add pressure to glue joint while drying and extra holding force.  It also depends on what might be placed on the shelf, a couple of nik naks is different from a 80 pound anvil.

Comment: This will hold probably 50 pounds at most, error budgeting two cats simultaneously with a computer monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would glue and put a couple of small screws in place just to help hold it. Make sure you pilot drill the screws so you don't split any of the wood.

Glue the joint, clamp it, pilot drill it, drive a couple of #4 wood screws and call it done.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something home made, and possibly not soundly designed, properly repaired it will be as strong as it was.  That may not be strong enough.

Comment: Because it was apparently made without screws or even nails, I agree the original work is very suspect.  I would put in a handful of deck screws , probably 2", maybe longer.